# Why does ommitting this one line from getopt_long() make a segfault?

Tags: c, gnu, glibc, getopt, getopt-long

After I compile using `gcc -Wall getopt.c -o options` and run a few examples, it seems to work at first glance. Purposely tripping it up makes it Segfault.

```
//straight from the man page
static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"add",     required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {"append",  no_argument,       0,  0 },
    {"delete",  required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {"verbose", no_argument,       0,  0 },
    {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
    {"file",    required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {0,         0,                 0,  0 } //<-- if i omit this line, it segfaults
};
```

**Why does it cause a Segmentation Fault when I omit that one line?**

or rather, asked in a different way

**Why must I initialize the last set of `struct option array` members to null?**

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: It is always recommended to read the `man` for the function BEFORE complaining.

Comment: I read the man page at least 20 times. My eyes are glazed over at this point. Maybe its just from being tired and not sleeping well and I don't think any of you truly understand my question here. The man page never states why. I honestly do not know why.

Comment: @jargonjunkie Your `why` has an obvious answer - because function needs to know where the list ends. The last record serves as terminator, it is a common idiom in C - use 0 or NULL terminator to indicate end of list, just like with strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. So the code processing the array knows when it's at the end. It's called a sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

From the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

> **The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.**
>
> ```
> struct option {
>            const char *name;
>            int         has_arg;
>            int        *flag;
>            int         val;
>        };
>
>  The meanings of the different fields are:
>
>   name   is the name of the long option.
>
>  has_arg
>        is: no_argument (or 0) if the option does not take an
>           argument; required_argument (or 1) if the option requires an
>           argument; or optional_argument (or 2) if the option takes an
>           optional argument.
>
>   flag   specifies how results are returned for a long option.  If flag
>           is NULL, then getopt_long() returns val.  (For example, the
>           calling program may set val to the equivalent short option
>           character.)  Otherwise, getopt_long() returns 0, and flag
>           points to a variable which is set to val if the option is
>           found, but left unchanged if the option is not found.
>
>   val    is the value to return, or to load into the variable pointed
>           to by flag.
>
>   The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros.
>
>   If longindex is not NULL, it points to a variable which is set to the
>    index of the long option relative to longopts.
> ```